# I'm looking for ways I can copy a list containing pygame. Surface objects

Tags: python, list, class, pygame, copy

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        self.lastMove = [None, None]

    def validate(self, piece:Piece, moves:list):
        wrong = []
        for x,y in moves:
            dupBoard = self.board.copy()
            dupPiece = piece.copy()
            piecex, piecey = piece.position
            dupPiece.position = (x,y)
            dupBoard[y][x] = dupPiece
            dupBoard[piecey][piecey] = None
            if self.kingIsChecked(dupBoard, piece.color):
                wrong.append((x, y))
        return list(set(moves)-set(wrong))
```

'board' in the class above contains instances of the 'Piece' class below

```
class Piece:
    def __init__(self, pos, identity, surface, color):
        self.position = pos
        self.identity = identity
        self.surface = surface
        self.color = color

    def getMoves(self):
    '''This function returns the possible moves of the piece'''
        pass

    def copy(self):
       return self
```

'surface' in this class contains a pygame.Surface object. E.g pygame.image.load("Black Knight.png")

I also created six more classes which are inheriting from the 'Piece' class which are: (Pawn,King,Queen,Bishop,Knight and Rook).
And the getMoves() function is different from one another

Board.validate() is a function that cross-checks all the moves of the piece (that is about to move) and makes sure that the move the piece is about to make does not put the king in danger.

The problem I'm having is that 'dupBoard' in Board.validate() is a reference to the actual 'Board.board' which means any change I make to dupBoard will affect the entire gameBoard(Board.board).

And I've tried to use the copy.deepcopy() function but it is giving me this error (can't pickle pygame.Surface objects).

Is there any other way I can copy Board.board or any way I can make this function better

Comment: You copy the list of pieces properly, it seems, using list.copy(). Keep in mind that this returns a shallow copy, I believe. This means the new list has the same class instances in it. However, your Piece copy seems to be wrong. Returning self is not a copy. You can import copy and call the copy.copy function or make the Piece.copy() function create a new object by calling into the Piece constructor.

Comment: @Starbuck5 `copy` module has `deepcopy` which can be used on the list to also copy the objects it contains

Comment: I've tried using copy.deepcopy on the list but because the classes in the list have pygame.Surface objects as attributes it gave me an error (can't pickle pygame.Surfaçe objects)

Comment: A `pygame.Surface` cannot be deep copied.

Comment: If you solved the problem, then you should answer the question yourself. (or delete the question)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem. Thanks to @Starbuck5 who said that using list.copy() will return a shallow copy of the list with the same class instances, so I created a copy method for the classes and used this method to copy the list

```
def copy ():
    newList = [[None for i in range(8)] for I in range(8)]
    for y in range(8):
        for x in range(8):
            if self.board[y][x]:
                newList[y][x] = self.board[y][X].copy()
    return newList
```